# How does a device retrieves a MAC address that corresponds to the IPv4 address of the device with which it wishes to communicate

Tags: networking, ipv4

I just need a brief explanation to that same question in the title. All help appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for `ARP`

Answer (score 1):

For IPv4, hosts use the ARP protocol – they *broadcast* an ARP query containing the wanted IP address, sending it to all hosts on the ethernet, and waiting for someone to reply with their own MAC address.

For IPv6, hosts use Neighbor Discovery, part of the ICMPv6 protocol. Again, they <del>broadcast</del> multicast an ND query with the IP address and wait for some host to respond.

(You can test this yourself using packet capture tools such as Wireshark to see what really happens on the wire, as well as tools such as `arping` to manually generate ARP queries for IPv4 or `ndisc6` for IPv6.)

After an answer is received, it's cached for several minutes in the system's "ARP table" or the "neighbor cache". This can be seen through `arp -n`, `ndp -n`, `ip neigh`, `netsh int ipv6 show neigh`, and such.